# What's the usual way <of/for> foreign travelers arriving at the airport <to visit/visiting> your hotel?

Tags: prepositions, infinitive-vs-gerund

When inquiring about the transportation from the airport to a hotel, which is better?

> a. What's the usual way **for** foreign travelers arriving at the airport **to** visit your hotel? 
> b. What's the usual way **of** foreign travelers arriving at the airport **to** visit your hotel?
> c. What's the usual way **of** foreign travelers arriving at the airport **visiting** your hotel?

Comment: It's **for** - but 'visit' is the wrong verb. I would suggest 'to **get to, travel to, transfer to**'.

Comment: @KateBunting Why is 'visit' wrong?

Comment: @listneva It's not actually wrong, it's just that 'get to' is less ambiguous. 'Best way' is unlikely to be misinterpreted, but it's not impossible that it could be.

Comment: *Visit* suggests spending less time: you might visit a hotel to have tea in the restaurant, but if you're staying overnight or for a few nights then you would use another verb.

Comment: _Visiting_ a place is spending time there, not travelling to it.

Comment: @PRL75 What's so ambiguous about 'visit' in context? My choices don't have 'best way'...

Comment: @StuartF Merriam-Webster defines 'visit' as "to go to see or stay at (a place) for a particular purpose (such as business or sightseeing)". Moreover, doesn't 'get to' suggest spending even less time than 'visit'?

Comment: @KateBunting But if we use 'get to', the inquiry might be interpreted as indicating that you're not going to be staying at the hotel, in which case they might not mention any free shuttle service provided by the hotel for its guests.

Comment: To me, "What's the usual way to visit the hotel?" invites the answer "Make a reservation in advance, then present yourself at reception." If an arriving traveller asks how to get there, I can't imagine an airport enquiry desk _not_ mentioning a shuttle service if one exists.

Comment: You don't visit a hotel usually,  you stay in/at one.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the best.

Possibly even better would be: "What's the **best** way for foreign travellers arriving at the airport to **get to** your hotel?"

Also, "foreign travellers" is pretty much superfluous since the best form of transport will be the same for everyone.